# GraphObject.make requires a class function or GoJS class name or name of an object builder, not: undefined

Tags: javascript, html, gojs

I'm following the tutorial of the library go.js: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EyseUD_i6Dw&list=PLOiCuGu6tcUSvKsqFnemvGTfdT97wVLsX&index=3.

I reached this point without problems, but at this point I'm getting this error:

```
GraphObject.make requires a class function or GoJS class name or name of an object builder, not: undefined
```

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gojs@2.2.5/release/go.js"></script>
    <script>
        function init() {
            var $ = go.GraphObject.make;
            myDiagram = $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv");
            myDiagram.add(
                $(go.Part, "Position",
                    $(go.Shape, "RoundedRectangle", {fill: "white"}),
                    $(go.textBlock, "some text")
                )
            );
            
        }
    </script>
</head> 
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="myDiagramDiv" style="height: 400px; width: 400px; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know where is the problem? Some version issue perhaps? I've tried with different versions of go.js, but I get always the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled `go.TextBlock` (you wrote `go.textBlock`)

By the way, in 2.2 (which was released after those videos were made), GoJS has a new way of constructing objects that looks like this:

```js
function init() {
  myDiagram = new go.Diagram("myDiagramDiv");
  myDiagram.add(
    new go.Part("Position")
      .add(new go.Shape("RoundedRectangle", {fill: "white"}))
      .add(new go.TextBlock("some text"))
  );
}
```

This method chaining like `new go.Part().add(someObject).add(anotherObject)` allows you to write code that is concise like `GraphObject.make`, but the errors are more clear. In the case of your typo, instead you would see:

`Uncaught TypeError: go.textBlock is not a constructor`

And it would point out the specific line:
[image]

Ro read more about method chaining instead of using `GraphObject.make`, see:
https://gojs.net/latest/changelog.html

https://gojs.net/latest/intro/buildingObjects.html